# Laravel 5.4: Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder::getRelated()

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I've been working on this for a week now, what I want to happen is that, to select the Level Rewards that have not been claimed by the user, but I'm getting an error which says: call to undefined `method::getRelated()`.

The claim_rewards table consists of

```
id, reward_id, user_id, status
```

So, if a user have 3 rewards to be claimed, and the user claims one reward, only the two remaining rewards should be displayed on the field, so I supposed a 'whereDoesNotHave' clause should work out, but I can't figure out how to fulfill the code to make it work.

Here is the code of the two scopes:

```
public function scopeClaimLevel($query)
{
    return $query->join('claim_rewards','claim_rewards.reward_id','=','level_rewards.id')->select('level_rewards.*');
}

public function scopeRewards($query)
{
   return $query = LevelRewards::whereDoesntHave('claimLevel')->whereDoesntHave('claim_rewards.status','=','0')->get();
}
```

I even tried this:

```
public function scopeGetRewards($query)
{
    return $query->claimLevel()
    ->whereDoesntHave('claimLevel', function (Builder $query) {
           $query->where('claim_rewards.status', '=', '0');
     }) 
    ->select('level_rewards.*')->get();
}
```

I even included this on the `LevelRewards` model:

```
use App\ClaimReward;
```

But I still get the same error. Any ideas on how to deal with this? Thank you.

Edit:

Here is the structure for the level_rewards table

```
id, level_required, item_name
```

That is why I made a scope into the LevelRewards model which is

```
public function scopeClaimLevel($query)
{
    return $query->join('claim_rewards','claim_rewards.reward_id','=','level_rewards.id')->select('level_rewards.*');
}
```

So that it would result to a constraint relationship to claim_rewards table

So if I put it into a Scenario, this will be the outcome:

I, as a user is on a level 20. I have three rewards to claim. Now, for my lists of rewards, I have level 10, 15, and 20 rewards to claim.
Now, I claimed the level 10 reward except for levels 15 and 20 rewards. So inside my claim_rewards table will have a data of that from level_rewards table that was claimed. Which will be the reward_id of the claim_rewards table.

So, if the level 10 reward that was claimed has a status of zero, then it will no longer be displayed into the field. The remaining rewards to be displayed is that those from level_rewards table that doesn't have a status of zero in the claim_rewards table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by adding a method but I just have 1 small problem, I cannot add another whereDoesntHave clause for the claim_reward.status:

```
public function rewards()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ClaimReward','reward_id');
}

public function scopeNotClaimed($query)
{
    return $query->whereDoesntHave('rewards');
}
```

Comment: The way you put your solution, you can now use a callback function as second argument to the `whereDoesntHave` function.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are using `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` in query scope, but you should instead use `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.

**UPDATE**

After a careful review of your code, I realized you are using `whereDoesntHave` with query scopes, but it can only be used with relationships. I suggest you refactor your query.

Comment: How do I exactly do that sir? I did use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder and  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model but same thing happens

Comment: Can you update the question with your controller code?

Comment: I don't have a controller for this one sir, it's only for the blade to display. So, if whereDoesntHave can only be used with relationships, how do I put it out in the method?

Comment: I'm starting to understand it. I just need the structure for `level_rewards` and I believe I can give you an answer.

Comment: I have added an additional details to the question, please check.

Comment: Added additional details to my question, please check.